# Boost::Python Forward Declaration of boost::python::object throwing python TypeError

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to refactor parts of my project, particularly the Python/C++ interface. 
The standard boost::python python initialization was working before:

```
boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
boost::python::object globals(main_module.attr("__dict__"));
```

//...

However, after factoring that into a class of its own, I'm getting

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: boost::python::api::proxy<boost::python::api::attribute_policies>
```

When an instantiating a PyInterface object, as below:

```
namespace py = boost::python;
class PyInterface
{
private:
    py::object
        main_module,
        global,
        tmp;
    //...
public:
    PyInterface();
    //...
};

PyInterface::PyInterface()
{
    std::cout << "Initializing..." << std::endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << "Accessing main module..." << std::endl;
    main_module = py::import("__main__");
    std::cout << "Retrieve global namespace..." << std::endl;
    global(main_module.attr("__dict__"));
    //...
}

//in test.cpp
int main()
{
    PyInterface python;
    //...
}

Running gives the following output:
Initializing...
Accessing main module...
Retrieving global namespace...

TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: boost::python::api::proxy<boost::python::api::attribute_policies>
```

The only thing I can think is that it has something to do with declaring "globals" before using it. In which case, is there another way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Fixed it.

Changing the call to globals in the constructor from

```
globals(main_method.attr("__dict__"));
```

to using the assignment operator instead:

```
globals = main_method.attr("__dict__");
```

Looking back, that seems perfectly obvious, but at least I know I wasn't the only one stumped judging by the lack of anyone derping me.